# How to test translation symmetry in Python?

Tags: python

We get two character values from a user that define a mapping (character translation), such as `'a' -> 'p'`. How would we test other pairs of strings to see if that same mapping/translation holds across all characters in the strings.  For example:

```
'abcd', 'pqrs' returns True
'aaa', 'ppp' returns True
'acb', 'pqr' returns False
'aab', 'pqr' returns False
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense as is; is this an incomplete question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to confirm that the offset (shift) of characters from one string to another is consistent.  Make sure the target strings are of the same length; calculate the offset and use `all()` and generator expression combination to try to ensure the logic completes on the first miss, if any, rather than continue checking:

```
def test(first, second, third, fourth):

    if len(third) != len(fourth):
        return False

    offset = ord(first) - ord(second)

    return all((ord(x) - ord(y)) == offset for x, y in zip(third, fourth))

>>> test('a', 'p', 'abcd', 'pqrs')
True
>>> test('a', 'p', 'aaa', 'ppp')
True
>>> test('a', 'p', 'acb', 'pqr')
False
>>> test('a', 'p', 'aab', 'pqr')
False
```

Comment: Nice work on both jobs. The question is actually comprehensible now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by subtracting the ASCII value with the first one from the user.

```
'abcd' = [97 98 99 100] subtract it by 'a' give you [0 1 2 3].
'pqrs' = [112 113 114 115] subtract it by 'p' give you [0 1 2 3].
```

so if the result of subtraction gives you the same result, return `True`